# CSS transition/animation cross browser not working

Tags: html, css

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7gvRT/) Link.

My problem is the animation is working fine on Firefox but somehow it is not working as expected in chrome.

Please view the fiddle in both the browser that is chrome & firefox & mouseover the image & you will see the difference.

GIven below is the stylesheet

===================================

```
.portfolio_container {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box figure a img {
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box .hover_effect {
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.thumbLink {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.thumbImage {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.thumbImage img{
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #7B133C;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
    display:none;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.5em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.thumbText {
    text-align: center;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90%;
}
.thumbImage:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
}
.touch-device .thumbImage:hover img {
    transform: none;
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
    opacity: 1;
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbText {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

## and here is my html

```
<section class="portfolio_container">


            <article class="portfolio">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="http://html5css3templates.com/themes/surrealstudio/templates/images/gallery/gallery-04-thumb.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="http://html5css3templates.com/themes/surrealstudio/templates/images/gallery/gallery-04.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>

        </section>
```

ANy help will be appritiated.

THanks

- Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your css

```
 .thumbImage:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
   -webkit-transform: scale(10); /* your forgot to add this -webkit prefix for crome */
   -ms-tranform:scale(10);    /** for ie10 browser **/
   -o-tranform:scale(10);    /** for opera browser **/
   -moz-transform: scale(10) /** for old mozilla browser **/
 }
```

here is demo fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/7gvRT/2/

Answer (score 0):

You did not add `-webkit` prefix to the transform property

```
.thumbImage:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
}
```

More about prefixes [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/)

Some more about prefixes

> CSS vendor prefixes or CSS browser prefixes are a way for browser makers to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and experimentation period. Browser prefixes are used to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

*Source* [About.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)